# Attribute converter for custom object not working as expected spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to encrypt data before persisting it into DB for one of my use case, I am using custom object and trying to encrypt one of the field while persisting it in the DB.

```
public class PIDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "referenceId")
    private String referenceId;

    @Column(name = "pdo")
    @Convert(converter = AttributeEncryptor.class)
    private PersonalDetails pdo;

    public PIDetails(String lender, String referenceId) {
        this.lender = lender;
        this.referenceId = referenceId;
    }

    public void setpdo(@NotNull BoardingDetails boardingDetails) {
        this.bfo = boardingDetails;
    }
}

public class PersonalDetails {
    private FinancialDetails.FinancialDetailsData financialDetails;  
}

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
@Getter
public class FinancialDetails extends OnboardingDetails {
    @NotNull(message = "financial data can't be null")
    private FinancialDetailsData data;

    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Builder
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public static class FinancialDetailsData {
        @JsonProperty("externalReferenceId")
        private String externalReferenceId;

        @JsonProperty("panNumber")
        private String panNumber;

        @JsonProperty("kycNo")
        private String kycNo;

        @JsonProperty("dob")
        private long dob;
    }

}


@Converter
public class AttributeEncryptor implements AttributeConverter<PersonalDetails, String> {

    private static final String AES = "AES";
    private static final String SECRET = "secret-key-12345";

    private final Key key;
    private final Cipher cipher;
    private Gson gson = new Gson();

    public AttributeEncryptor() throws Exception {
        key = new SecretKeySpec(SECRET.getBytes(), AES);
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES);
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(PersonalDetails personalDetails) {
        try {
            if(!isEncryptedString(personalDetails.getFinancialDetails().getPanNumber())){
                String encryptedPan = encrypt(personalDetails.getFinancialDetails().getPanNumber());
                personalDetails.getFinancialDetails().setPanNumber(encryptedPan);
            }
            String personalDetailsJson= gson.toJson(personalDetails);
            return personalDetailsJson;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public PersonalDetails convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        try {
            PersonalDetails personalDetails = gson.fromJson(dbData, PersonalDetails.class);
            String panNumber = decrypt(personalDetails.getFinancialDetails().getPanNumber());
            personalDetails.getFinancialDetails().setPanNumber(panNumber);
            return personalDetails;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    public  String encrypt(String attribute){
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(attribute.getBytes()));
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException | InvalidKeyException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    public  String decrypt(String attribute){
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
            return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(attribute)));
        } catch (InvalidKeyException | BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    public boolean isEncryptedString(String attribute) {
        try {
            decrypt(attribute);
            return true;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

but it is not working as expected , couple of issues are there
while saving the `convertToDatabaseColumn` function is called more then once and while reading the data I am not getting the decrypted value.

I am using spring jpa for persistent and retrieval of data.

repository.save() for saving data - it is being called while saving the data, but it is looping and calling `convertToDatabaseColumn` 4 times and it also calls `convertToEntityAttribute`.
repository.findByReferenceIdAndName() while retrieving data :- this time `convertToEntityAttribute` is not being called.

what is wrong with this code ?

Comment: For starters stop using 2 different json libraries, stick with 1. How are you reading/saving the data.

Comment: @M.Deinum spring JPA